# Alpha Decay and Liquid drop model

Tags: nuclear-physics

So I am having a bit of trouble wording my way thought this question, which indicated to me, I may not understand everything fully.

Here is the question
Explain with reference to the liquid drop model why most alpha emitters have a larger mass number A>100.

So here are my key points I have made so far.

1. At higher levels of atomic mass the binding energy decreases which is due to the Colombo repulsion that occurs ate a rate of $z^2$
2. And this is where I am a bit hazy. The reason for the dominate effect of the Colombo force is due to the deformation of the nucleus which means that the surface term is decreasing and cant maintain the equilibrium state of the nucleus due to the Colombo repulsion.
3. The reason why an alpha particle is chosen is that is extremely stable due to it high binding energy and that compared to the mass od it constitutes i.e the protons and nurtons it is relatively low. Aslo alpha decay allow for a positive release of K.E, which I have a feeling and I am not sure this energy has something to do with the reduce mass energy, of the nucleus

Comment: Hint: the nuclear force that holds the nucleus together has a finite (short) range, while the Coulomb force has an unlimited range.

Comment: I understand that, but I cant seem to link what your saying with the question. I am having trouble linking it to the liquid drop model itself.

Comment: Since the nuclear force has a short range, its strength is essentially proportional to the number of nearest neighbors a nucleon has. Does the number of nearest neighbors change much as the nucleus gets bigger?

Comment: No, if I am thinking correctly though there are more nurtons and protons being added the nuclear force is not for a particlular cluster of a particular cluster. So what I am trying to say is that if I have say 4 electrons I have 6 connections in that cluster, the nuclear force wont change as more nucleons are added, it will remain the same. So there fore the Colombo force become greater than the nulcear force for this reason. Is this along the correct lines?

Comment: one can consider alpha clustering in heavy nuclei  as a favour to alpha emissions.moreover the  particles share quite a large part of Q-value of  the reaction and the daughters are closer to their ground state.